# Tally prime 2.1 is not fetching data under the given date

Tags: xml, tally

I was not able to fetch data of the below applied date. It fetches the whole data and also I'm not using education mode.

```
 <CURRENTCOMPANY>${company}</CURRENTCOMPANY>
 <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
 <SVFROMDATE>1-Apr-2022</SVFROMDATE>
 <SVTODATE>31-Apr-2022</SVTODATE>
```

I want to get only one month data, but it is not possible using the above code.

Comment: What do you mean by "under the date"? Do you mean ***before*** the date? Or ***on*** the date? Or for the given dates (a range of dates)? Or something else? Can you provide an example?

Comment: i'm representing the date period which is given on the below code snippet @PeterMortensen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The company tag is wrong and for dates, use type="DATE":

```
    <SVFROMDATE TYPE="DATE">{{Fromdate}}</SVFROMDATE>
    <SVTODATE TYPE="DATE">{{ToDate}}</SVTODATE>
     <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>{{Company}}</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
```

Comment: Your code is working... Is there any possible way to apply date on tally education mode also?

Comment: you can apply date filter but with some limitations, you can only use start and end of month and end of month should be 31 only